# Yolov5 Convert to ONNX

Tags: torch, onnx, yolov5

I am trying to convert Yolov5 that takes as input dynamic image shapes into onnx.

```
import torch
from app import onnx_tools

# This is an example of usage of onnx converter.
yolo5_layout = '/home/eirini/Downloads/best.pt'
model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", 'custom', path=yolo5_layout, source='local')
model.eval()

# Example case
dummy_input = torch.rand((1, 3, 224, 224))

# Passing a dictionary where you define that batch size dimension, width and height are dynamic
dynamic_axes_dict = {"actual_input": {0: "bs",
                                      2: "img_x",
                                      3: "img_y"},
                     "output": {0: "bs",
                                }}

# In this example, we told PyTorch to set the axes at indices 0, 2 and 3 of “actual_input” to be dynamic
# and to set the 0 index of “output” to be dynamic – where a dynamic shape is represented as an arbitrary
# string rather than a numerical value (e.g., `img_x` and `img_y` instead of 224 and 224).
torch.onnx.export(model= model,
                  args= dummy_input,
                  f = "mytest.onnx",
                  export_params= True,
                  verbose= False,
                  input_names=["actual_input"],
                  output_names=["output"],
                  opset_version=14,
                  dynamic_axes=dynamic_axes_dict)
```

The above code produces an onnx model. Then I try to load this model by passing a random example.

```
import numpy as np
import onnxruntime as ort

ort_session = ort.InferenceSession("mytest.onnx")

outputs = ort_session.run(
    None,
    {"actual_input": np.random.randn(10, 3, 960, 1200).astype(np.float32)},
)
print(outputs[0])
```

But I get the following error:

onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running Concat node. Name:'/model/model/model.12/Concat' Status Message: concat.cc:159 PrepareForCompute Non concat axis dimensions must match: Axis 3 has mismatched dimensions of 75 and 76`

It seems like I accepts 224,224 but the purpose of dynamic axes was to handle variant shapes

Comment: torch== 1.13.0 , 
onnx == 1.12.0 ,
onnxruntime==1.13.1